# The line that is normal to the curve $x^2+3xy-4y^2=0$ at ​(3​,3​) intersects the curve at what other​ point?

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

> The line that is normal to the curve $$x^2+3xy-4y^2=0$$ at $​(3​,3​)$ intersects the curve at what other​ point ?

Using implicit differentiation I got the normal line $y=5x-12$ but now I need to find the other intersecting point. What do I do from here?

Comment: Solve the sytem of two equations that you have

Comment: Simply substitute $y=5x-12$ in the equation of the curve.

Comment: @MostafaAyaz the equation of the normal to the curve is probably wrong  $y=-x+6$ is the normal to the curve

Comment: @Aryadeva how did you get that equation?

Comment: @Aryadeva, yes you are right. The equation must be $y=-x+6$.

Comment: How did you arrive at your equation for the normal? Show your work and someone will be able to point out where you went wrong.

Comment: I think you made a mistake with differentiation Karl

Comment: 2x+3xy'+3y-8yy' and then solving for y' i got y'=(-2x-3y)/(3x-8y) and plugged in (3,3) and got -15/-15 ---- oh... i see what I did wrong, I didn't do the numerator calculations correct the first time...

Comment: Solve the system of the two equations you have Kari

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2+3xy-4y^2=0$$
Differentiate:
$$2x+3y+3xy'-8yy'=0$$
At $(3,3)$ the slope for the tangent line is:
$$15=15y' \implies y'=1$$
$$y=x$$
The normal line is therefore:
$$y=-x+b$$
With $(x,y)=(3,3) \implies b=6$
$$y=-x+6$$

Plug this in the original equation to get the intersection points:
$$x^2+3xy-4y^2=0$$
$$x^2+3x(-x+6)-4(-x+6)^2=0$$
Solve for x the equation.

[image: graphing the equation]

Comment: how did you find b?

Comment: the normal line goes through the point (3,3) Kari @KariSnow

Comment: In green it's the normal line @KariSnow

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to exploit the fact that the equation $ \ x^2 + 3xy - 4y^2 \ = \ 0 \ $ describes a "degenerate" conic.  Since we can factor the (bi-variate) polynomial as $ \ (x - y)·(x + 4y) \ = \ 0 \ \ , $ this "curve" is actually the union of the two lines $ \ y \ = \ x \ $ and $ \ x \ = \ -4y \ $ (or $ \ y \ = \ -\frac14 x \ ) \ . $ [This is seen in **user235711131**'s graph.]  The point $ \ (3 \ , \ 3) \ $ is on the line $ \ y \ = \ x \ \ ; $ since the slope of the line is $ \ m \ = \ 1 \ \ , $ the slope of a normal line to a point on this line is $ \ -\frac{1}{m} \ = \ -1 \ \ . $  Hence, the equation of the normal line at the given point is $ \ y - 3 \ = \ (-1)·(x - 3) \ \ $ or $ \ y \ = \ -x + 6 \ $ (as found in many of the other posts and comments).

Since this line is not parallel to either of the component lines of the degenerate conic, it must intersect each of them.  We already have the intersection $ \ (3 \ , \ 3) \ $ on $ \ y \ = \ x \ \ , $ so we want to find the intersection of the normal line with $ \ x \ = \ -4y \ \ . $  We have a choice of ways to do this; one is to solve
$$ x \ = \ -4y \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ -4·(-x + 6) \ = \ 4x - 24 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 3x \ = \ 24 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ 8 $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \   y \ = \  (-8  ) + 6 \ = \ -2 \ \ .  $$

Thus, the second intersection point of the chosen normal line with the degenerate conic is at $ \ (8 \ , \ -2) \ \ $ (as also seen in the posted graph).